the clean up function of the Ref callback is not executed
Here in my React the clean up function is not executed when re-rendering:
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(2);
  const d = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>
      <p ref={(node) => {
        console.log('start');
        return () => {
          console.log('finish');
        };
      }}>{x}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setX(x + 1)}>hello</button>
    </>
  );
}

I want my clean up function to be executed when the ref callback is updated hence here the callback is created every render then the clean up must be executed every render!

refs don't have cleanup functions. If you need one, a ref is probably not the right tool for the job. What is it you're trying to do with the ref?

Where did you get the idea this would work (and do what)? Are you thinking of useEffect?

In case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (you earn a badge BTW) there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after someone answers that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Ref cleanups are only available in canary builds of React, so currently not available in stable versions, if you want to play around with it, you need to use a canary build for the time being, or test for null like Drew suggests in his answer:


function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(2);

   return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p ref={(node) => {
          console.log('start', node);
          return () => {
            console.log('finish', node);
          };
        }}>{x}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setX(x + 1)}>hello</button>
      </React.Fragment>
  );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body);

root.render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.0-canary-c3048aab4-20240326/umd/react.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-N3bJHd0IQK3T+qeOxAxW+CC1/dYPREk4z6UvuqDrbk1DcK173oFL2RjSDwS1F5nLMaPwI3v4yWXCtuf2rYw3/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.0-canary-c3048aab4-20240326/umd/react-dom.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-36i1/IQRwia35jjTQr9i7Hsb/CaU8B5I0CL6/JMnOO7XExnCKXhsNR14c15DhSswOvN7KpH6qYAoCiJVvn3QBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>




React refs don't have a cleanup function in the same way the useEffect hook callback returns a cleanup function. React refs that are set with the callback syntax are simply just called again and passed null.
Example:


function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(2);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span
        ref={(node) => {
          if (node) {
            console.log("start", node);
          } else {
            console.log("finish", node);
          }
        }}
      >
        {x}
      </span>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => setX((x) => x + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />



In the ref callback, check when the ref is null and handle any "cleanup" duties.
Note: It's more conventional/standard to use a useEffect hook to run any cleanup logic.


function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(2);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("start");
    return () => {
      console.log("finish");
    };
  }, [x]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>
        {x}
      </span>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => setX((x) => x + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />




please looks at this section of the docs  btw the reason why it does not work for me becasue  the feature is still on The Canary Channels only:
https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#:~:text=This%20example%20shows%20another%20approach%20for%20managing%20the%20Map%20with%20a%20ref%20callback%20cleanup%20function.

@saidmhamdi Yup, I got that much also from Nick's answer.
